# Which Captain ordered the most Crew to their deaths?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-enterprise

Currently rewatching all of Voyager, and remembering how callous Janeway was in ordering Tuvix's death. And how many times she threatens to, and actually activates the Self-Destruct Sequence.

I wonder, which Star Trek series or captain has actually ordered the most Crew to their death? (not actually dying, but at least knowing that it was most probable outcome, ala Troi's bridge officer training exam)

Alternatively, which Captain threatens/orders the most Self Destructs?

Comment: My gut tells me high to low, Janeway, Sisko, Picard/Kirk. Don't even know where Archer would stand in this.

Comment: Loosely speaking, I think Janeway wins just with the order to destroy the Caretaker's array in the first episode. Her entire crew condemned to near-certain death in a 70+ year trip through uncharted space

Comment: Zapp Brannigan beats them all, hands down.

Comment: If we were to stretch the parameters of the question  to include orders that *unintentionally* caused the death of crew members, I'd say Matt Decker from the TOS ep "*The Doomsday Machine*."  He ordered his entire crew down to the third planet of a system to save them, but that planet was then destroyed by the Doomsday Machiine.

Comment: Sisko started a war that the Federation needed the Romulans to win...and had casualties in the billions. That has to count for something.

Comment: You could argue that as Locutus, Picard ordered everyone in Starfleet to their deaths.

Comment: Do you count activating the self-destruct?  Or giving orders in a combat situation?  Or just situations like in Troi's commander exam?

Comment: Janeway for "That idea Harry Kim has about using a shuttle to navigate ahead of in slipstream has a chance of not destroying the ship."  Followed by "The ship is under too much stress in zero gravity at post slipstream velocity - let's attempt to land - like an airplane with a broken window trying to re-pressurize".  Kills all but 2.  Uses time travel to undo.

Comment: Are you including alternative timelines, parallel universes, copies of the main crew, etc.?

Answer (score 11):

## My vote goes to Picard

First of all, Picard is no stranger to the auto-destruct sequence, as in ["11001001"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/11001001_(episode)) and ["Where Silence Has Lease"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Where_Silence_Has_Lease_%28episode%29).  The crew complement of the Enterprise-D is much higher than those of the other primary *Star Trek* ships that we encounter, and also includes families and civilian employees. (See [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/52666/40294) for crew complement information regarding the Enterprise-D.)

In ["Lower Decks"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lower_Decks_(episode)), Picard sends Ensign Sito on a mission for which the chance of survival is known in advance to be extremely low.  In fact, she does not survive.

Finally, in *[Star Trek: Nemesis](https://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Nemesis)*, Picard rams the Enterprise-E nose first into the Scimitar, without ordering an evacuation of the forward saucer section (nor did he give time for one).

At best, there was:

> *All hands, brace for impact.*

In fact, I had previously raised a question about this:

[Warning regarding forward saucer section in Nemesis?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79522/warning-regarding-forward-saucer-section-in-nemesis)

Comment: See [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52605/what-is-the-crew-complement-and-capacity-of-the-galaxy-class#52666) where you can get some numbers on the number of people Picard was going to sentence to death aboard the *D* ;)  Bear in mind the *E* was actually a smaller ship than the *D*

Comment: Not to mention whatever mayhem Picard caused as Locutus.

Comment: The question asks about crew not civilians, do we actually know how many were crew and not civilians?

Comment: @Matt : Yes, we do.  Unlike the Enterprise-D, there were no families aboard the Enterprise-E (see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84849/).  Barring the possibility of a few civilian staff or scientists, etc., the ship was by and large populated by active crew.

Comment: @Praxis fair enough, your first 2 paragraphs focused on D, which made me think of  D while reading the rest +1

Comment: Don't forget alternate history Picard sacrificing the entire ship so that the Enterprise C could escape.

Comment: "11001001" barely counts for number-of-crew-killed, only Riker and Picard (plus a handful of Bynar space pirates) were aboard at the time.

Answer (score 9):

Well, according to [a contribution to *Cracked*](https://www.cracked.com/photoplasty_1602_22-insane-stats-that-change-how-you-see-fictional-universes_p3/) (entry #7) by someone calling themselves [RogerRamjet](https://www.cracked.com/members/RogerRamjet/):

> [image: An overview showing photos of Enterprise captains, with percentages of crew killed, represented by red-shirted crew members. Information is transcribed below.]
>
> #### Percentage of the Crew Killed While They Were the Captain
>
> - Captain Jean-Luc Picard: 7%
> - Captain James T. Kirk: 22%
> - Captain Kathryn Janeway: 37%
> - Captain Jonathan Archer: 67%
>
> *...not counting the books, comics, movies, post-death revivals, dream sequences, parallel universes, or multi-death timeloops.*

Comment: Using percentage here isn't really fair for Archer considering that they had a complement of ~80 each death is more than 1%. Picard could lose a few dozen per each percent.

Comment: No entry for Captain Sisko?

Comment: @RichS: I know it's been a while since you asked but... I would imagine that measuring Sisko's percentage is very complicated. First, you have to figure out DS9's crew complement (does Rom count?), then you have to figure out what fraction of that is Federation vs. Bajoran (or do we care?), and *then* you have to do the exact same calculation for the *Defiant* and somehow combine it with the DS9 number. Also, what the heck do you do with "The Siege of AR-558"? Do any of those people count, or are they not part of DS9's crew and therefore not counted?

Comment: 'what the heck do you do with "The Siege of AR-558"' — personally, I watch it just before a *Better Call Saul* rewatch and imagine the weird time-travel shenanigans that resulted in [Vargas](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vargas) being resurrected in the 20th century as [Tuco Salamanca](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Tuco_Salamanca).

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd vote for Commodore Matt Decker, in "The Doomsday Machine" (TOS).  He attempted to save his crew by beaming them all down to a planet, only to then watch helplessly as the machine then *consumed the entire planet*.  That means he managed to kill off *his ENTIRE crew* in one shot (and went a bit off the rails due to the resulting grief).

Comment: he wasn't expecting them to die though - I think OP is asking about deliberately knowing crew deaths would happen